# Change value and text of button

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a textbox and a button with an onClick event connected to it, and when the button is clicked once I want to change the text of the button and clear the textbox. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on a postback (a complete refresh of the page), simply put code in your button click handler to set these values. For example, `textbox.Text = string.Empty;`

If you want to set it on the client side (without refreshing the page), then you'd need to use client script such as JavaScript.

Comment: I want to do it on a postback.

Answer (score 1):

This needs you to know about TextBox and its properties. Normally the value of a textbox you use its Text property as TextBox1.Text. In your case you put this statement in the button's click event

```
string txtValue=TextBox1.Text;
TextBox1.Text=string.Empty;
```

To see how to use TextBox and its properties. [This can help](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/aspnet-basics-working-with-the-textbox-control/606)